# cannot display data except razor string type in webpage

Tags: asp.net, razor

I did define variable like this to display userid

```
 userid = row.userid;
```

but getting this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'
```

Please help

Comment: Is there something about that error message that is not very clear what the problem is to you? It shows you are trying to put an int where a string needs to be, so you need to convert the int to a string, or change userid to be an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
userid = row.userid.ToString();
```

Comment: Just another question how do i show username based on userid on web page ?

Answer (score 0):

`userid = row.userid.ToString()` ?